# Запрос на соединение двух таблиц в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, просто составить запрос-образец.

Есть первая таблица, в которой есть столбцы `спортсмен` и `серийный_номер_велосипеда`.
Вторая таблица: `серийный_номер_велосипеда`, `цвет`, `год_выпуска`.

Какой будет единый запрос, чтобы выбрать `спортсмен`, `серийный_номер_велосипеда`, `цвет`, `год_выпуска`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Используйте [**соединение таблиц**](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html):

1. Если список серийных номеров велосипеда в обеих таблиц совпадает (нет таких элементов, которые есть в одной таблице, но нет во второй), то можете использовать внутреннее соединение **`join`** (`inner join`):

   ```
   SELECT s.sportsman, s.serial, b.color, b.year
   FROM sportsmen s JOIN bike b ON s.serial = b.serial
   ```

   Пример таблицы на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2c8)

   Результат [выполнения запроса](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2c8/1)

   ---

   Либо:

   ```
   SELECT s.sportsman, s.serial, b.color, b.year
   FROM sportsmen s, bike b
   WHERE s.serial = b.serial
   ```

   Результат [выполнения запроса](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd2c8/2)

---

2. Если список серийных номеров велосипедов не совпадает, то при соединении таблиц с помощью внутреннего соединения `inner join` (`join`) можно потерять нужные строки, **поэтому** для сохранения всех строк в левой таблице надо использовать **`left join`**:

   ```
   SELECT s.sportsman, s.serial, b.color, b.year
   FROM sportsmen s LEFT JOIN bike b ON s.serial = b.serial
   ```

   Пример таблицы на [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc902)

   Результат [выполнения запроса](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bbc902/1)

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT с.спортсмен, в.серийный_номер_велосипеда, в.цвет, в.год_выпуска 
   FROM спортсмен с LEFT JOIN велосипед в
      ON с.серийный_номер_велосипеда = в.серийный_номер_велосипеда;
```

Comment: выдаст ошибку - не будет знать, из какой таблицы в select'e брать `серийный_номер_велосипеда`

Comment: Не согласен. Left join связывает две таблицы по полю `серийный_номер_велосипеда` и оно выведется. Попробуйте сами. Я делаю точно такие же запросы ко своей базе и все работает (в противном случае не писал бы).

Comment: он выдаст ошибку `Ambiguous column name`, так как не будет знать, из какой таблицы в select'e брать столбец `серийный_номер_велосипеда` - из таблицы `спортсмен` или из `велосипед`

Comment: Да, действительно,я забыл кое-что дописать в ответе... Сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 7):

Вам нужна инструкция [left join](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

```
select t1.*, t2.color, t2.year
from t1 left join t2
     on t1.serial_num = t2.serial_num
```