# MySQL запрос состоящий из четырех таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

1) Напишите запрос, который выводит имена всех учеников, сдавших экзамен по математике у профессора Иванова на оценку 4 или 5. 2) Напишите запрос, выводящий имена учеников, пропустивших экзамен по математике у профессора Иванова.

1)

```
SELECT name 
FROM t_students 
JOIN t_teachers ON WHERE t_teachers.name = "Иванов" 
JOIN t_exams ON WHERE t_exams.exam_name = "Математика" 
JOIN t_marks ON WHERE t_marks .mark = 4 AND 5
```

2)

```
SELECT name 
FROM t_students 
JOIN t_teachers ON WHERE t_teachers.name = "Иванов" 
JOIN t_exams ON WHERE t_exams.exam_name = "Математика" 
JOIN t_marks ON WHERE t_marks .mark = NULL
```

Ребят можете посмотреть правильно ли я выполнил?

[image: таблицы]

Comment: а вы проверяли запрос? синтаксическая ошибка видь

Comment: Посмотрите [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565664/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86-%D0%B2-mysql?rq=1), поправте у себя.

Answer (score -3):

Вот вам пример:

```
$query_firms = mysql_query("select ls.id, ls.title, ls.id_parameter, ls.drag, ls.url, COUNT(`l`.`id`) AS `rcnt`, (`st`.`id`) AS `param`
    from leads_sort ls
       left join status st on ls.id_parameter = st.leadssort and st.id_cabinet = ls.id_cabinet and st.vid = 'leads' 
       left join lids l on st.id = l.status and l.id_cabinet = ls.id_cabinet and l.id_staff = $id_staff and l.delete_status = '0'
    where ls.id_cabinet = $id_cabinet and ls.vid = 'leads'
    group by ls.id
    order by ls.drag");
```

Этот запрос выводит все Лиды, которые находятся в определенном Статусе, а статус находится уже в определенном Уровне сортировки.

Работает так:

```
Сортировка (вкладка): Выполены
Статусы привязанные к сортировке(вкладке) Выполнены: Успешно; Продано; Реализовано
Клиенты в статусах: Успешно; Продано; Реализовано
```

Comment: Для заданного вопроса этот ответ - на уровне оффтопа. Не говоря уж о том, что результат в таком запросе будет ошибочно-кратным, а mysql_query устарел на два потопа.